# How to reload system with flex image using softlayer REST API

Tags: java, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to reload a bare metal system with the following flex image but it isn't persisting.  Is there something I'm doing wrong is the REST call?

```
    String content = "{\"parameters\":[\"FORCE\",{\"sshKeyIds\":["+sshKeys+"]},{\"imageTemplateId\":803303}]}";

    Response response = RestAssured.given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).body(content).post("https://"+username+":"+apikey+"@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/"+softlayer_id+"/reloadOperatingSystem.json");
```

Comment: Not enough information... if you try to manually curl the same exact HTTP call - does it persist ?

Comment: No, same outcome.  The softlayer backend isn't using the imageTemplateId specified in the call.  What more information do you need? @alfasin

Comment: If it has the same outcome - why are you looking for issues in the code ? look for the reason on the other (receiving) side.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following **`Rest`** request using [SoftLayer_Hardware_Server::reloadOperatingSystem](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/reloadOperatingSystem):

```
URL:

https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/[Hardware_Id]/reloadOperatingSystem

Method: POST

Json Payload:

{
  "parameters": [
    "50ecea4c6cc06fa1eb346b5f627adfaa",
    {
      "imageTemplateId": 295000
    }
  ]
}

Where:

“50ecea4c6cc06fa1eb346b5f627adfaa” is the token (The token will remain active for 10 minutes)
“295000” the image template to use
```

• But, How to get the token for our above configuration?

Execute:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/[Hardware_Id]/reloadOperatingSystem

Method: GET
```

Comment: I tried this and no difference, still is not taking the image specified and no error.
`curl -X GET https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/899667/reloadOperatingSystem.json
"3e60ca26217db1d5270a598070b5b924"`

`content = "{\"parameters\":[\"3e60ca26217db1d5270a598070b5b924\",{\"sshKeyIds\":["+sshKeys+"]},{\"imageTemplateId\":803303}]}";`

`RestAssured.given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).body(content).post("https://"+username+":"+apikey+"@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/"+softlayer_id+"/reloadOperatingSystem.json");`

Comment: It is a public flex Image I'm trying to use.
`  {  
    "accountId":330024,
    "createDate":"2015-10-30T05:43:09-08:00",
    "id":803303,
    "name":"QRadar-7.2.6-RHEL-6.7-BareMetal-20151030",
    "note":"This image can be used to load a bare metal host to then install QRadar 7.2.6.",
    "parentId":null,
    "publicFlag":1,
    "statusId":1,
    "summary":"QRadar 7.2.6 RHEL Base Image for Bare Metals",
    "transactionId":null,
    "userRecordId":194906,
    "globalIdentifier":"2bfb1d21-4a02-4ade-8ce6-3e00d825923b"
  },`

Comment: It seems to be a user problem permissions. To confirm this, please, execute a reload by using `Control Portal` with your `username` and see if the option to reload is available for you. Maybe you need to add a  permission to issue OS Reloads. Regards.

Comment: Nope, the system reloads but doesn't reload with the specified image.