# How to reload OS using a specific flex image from slcli

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

[How to reload system with flex image using softlayer REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551817/how-to-reload-system-with-flex-image-using-softlayer-rest-api) specifies how to do a reload using REST.  How do I do it from the "slcli" command?

Using "slcli server reload --help" doesn't show any option to specify the imageTemplateId.  It only enables sshKeys and install scripts.

Using the "slcli call-api..." I don't understand if it's possible to pass parameters. It really doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slcli is not able to do that, I recomend you to use python scrips to call the API.

see this example about reloads:
https://gist.github.com/softlayer/2789898

and here an example to reload from an image template, you just need to make sure that the imagetemplate id is the correct for your flex image:

```
"""
Reload servers from a list of IPs

This script looks for a server with a determinate IP address and reload it from an image template.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/findByIpAddress
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/reloadOperatingSystem

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""

import SoftLayer
import json

ipsToReload = ['184.172.45.215', '1.1.1.1']

# Call the Softlayer_Account::getPrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups method.
# to get the images templates in the account.
imageTemplateId = 51236

USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
hardwareService = client['SoftLayer_Hardware_Server']


failedServers = []
for ipToReload in ipsToReload:
    failedServer = {}
    failedServer['ip'] = ipToReload
    try:
        server = hardwareService.findByIpAddress(ipToReload)
        if server == '':
            failedServer['error'] = "Ip does not exist."
            failedServers.append(failedServer)
            continue
    except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
        failedServer['error'] = e
        failedServers.append(failedServer)
        continue
    if 'activeTransaction' in server:
        failedServer['error'] = "There is an active transaction."
        failedServers.append(failedServer)
        continue

    config = {
        'imageTemplateId': imageTemplateId
    }

    try:
        reload = hardwareService.reloadOperatingSystem('FORCE', config, id=server['id'])
    except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
        failedServer['error'] = e
        failedServers.append(failedServer)
        continue

print("The reload failed for these IPs:")
print(json.dumps(failedServers, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))
```

Regards