# Taking an existing private image and flash to another server

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to figure out a way to take an existing private exported standard image template to flash to another server / instance. Looking through the API, I haven't been able to find anything, i've only found way to look up the private images on has. (Doing this via python / custom module ansible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the image template is being listed here: https://control.softlayer.com/devices/images

if you can see the imagetemplate so you can use the reload method, see the code example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37735767/how-to-reload-os-using-a-specific-flex-image-from-slcli), make sure that you are using the correct image templateID

this code can help you to list your image templates:

```
"""
Get private image template

the script calls the SoftLayer_Account::getPrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups method
to list the private templates in the account and uses an object mask
to display more related information of the images templates

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getPrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/dataypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Declare the API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
accountService = client['SoftLayer_Account']

# declaring an object mask to get more information about the images templates
objectMask = "mask[summary,note,status[name],storageRepository[datacenter],transaction[transactionGroup,transactionStatus],children[storageRepository[datacenter],blockDevices[diskImage[type]]]]"

try:
    result = accountService.getPrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups(mask=objectMask)
    print(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    """
    # If there was an error returned from the SoftLayer API then bomb out with the
    # error message.
    """
    print("Unable to retrieve the list of image templates. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

also may this code can help you to create your image template, in case you are not able to see it in the portal, make sure that the image template is in one of your clusters of object storage.

```
"""
Create Image Template from external source

This script creates a transaction to import a disk image from an external source and create 
a standard image template

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/createFromExternalSource
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Configuration
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer

# Your SoftLayer username and apiKey
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Declare the group name to be applied to the imported template
name = 'imageTemplateTest'
# Declare the note to be applied to the imported template
note = 'This is for test Rcv'

'''
Declare referenceCode of the operating system software description for the imported VHD
available options: CENTOS_6_32, CENTOS_6_64, CENTOS_7_64, REDHAT_6_32, REDHAT_6_64, REDHAT_7_64, 
UBUNTU_12_32, UBUNTU_12_64, UBUNTU_14_32, UBUNTU_14_64, WIN_2003-STD-SP2-5_32, WIN_2003-STD-SP2-5_64, 
WIN_2008-STD-R2-SP1_64, WIN_2012-STD_64.
'''
operatingSystemReferenceCode = 'CENTOS_6_64'

'''
Define the parameters below, which refers to object storage where the image template is stored. 
It will help to build the uri.
'''
# Declare the object storage account name
objectStorageAccountName = 'SLOS307608-10'
# Declare the cluster name where the image is stored
clusterName = 'dal05'
# Declare the container name where the image is stored
containerName = 'OS'
# Declare the file name of the image stored in the object storage, it should be .vhd or 
fileName = 'testImage2.vhd-0.vhd'

"""
Creating an SoftLayer_Container_Virtual_Guest_block_Device_Template_Configuration Skeleton
which contains the information from external source
"""
configuration = {
    'name': name,
    'note': note,
    'operatingSystemReferenceCode': operatingSystemReferenceCode,
    'uri': 'swift://'+ objectStorageAccountName + '@' + clusterName + '/' + containerName + '/' + fileName
}

# Declare the API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
groupService = client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group']

try:
    result = groupService.createFromExternalSource(configuration)
    print(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to create the image template from external source. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)
```